# No display after "updating" intel HD graphics driver

Tags: lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics, display-driver, switchable-graphics

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y460 running Win7 x64 SP1, with switchable graphics - Intel HD / Mobility Radeon 5650.

When I tried to update my Intel hd graphics driver through Device Manager (Display adapters, right-clicked Intel HD Graphics, Driver tab, "update driver", "search automatically for updated driver software"), Device Manager for some reason changed "Intel HD graphics" to "Standard VGA graphics adapter" and resolution became 800x600. I rebooted, but after that, I couldn't roll back the driver (button was greyed out in Device Manager).

I first tried the HD graphics driver from Intel's website for my processor (i5 430 M) but that had a driver signing issue. After disabling the driver signing enforcement, it led to the no-display issue, details in the next paragraph.

I subsequently tried to install the Intel HD Graphics driver from the Lenovo support site (IN2VDO26WW6.exe), but after rebooting, there is no display after the "Starting Windows" screen. The sound at the login screen plays, and I can enter my password and have it log in (based on sound cues), and apparently everything loads fine (can shutdown using Run command), just that there is no display.

I have tried setting my laptop's date to near the driver's date, to no avail.

I have tried deleting the registry keys at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Intel/Display

HKEY_CURRENT_User/Software/Intel/Display

HKEY_CURRENT_User/Software/Intel/ICC/Applications/Intel Graphics Driver
```

and reinstalling the driver, also to no avail.

Booting up from a Linux (lubuntu) livedisk thumbdrive works, with 1366x768  display resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

I have asked the same question on Lenovo's forum, but have received no replies...

(Yes I did a very stupid thing that caused this whole mess. :C  T_T  )

Comment: Can you remote into it with RDC to roll back the driver? btw, there's very little chance that graphics chip has new drivers, it's a legacied device.

Comment: "Roll-back driver" option in Device Manager is greyed out... Also I think it's no longer an option, what with the number of times I've tried reinstalling it.

Comment: You can try [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-v17054-released) which supports Intel graphics along with AMD and Nvidia.  It's best to run it in Windows Safe Mode.  Normally that's done using the Windows GUI.  Since you have no display there you can also get into safe mode by interrupting the boot process three times in a row.  While the computer is booting just hold the power button until it shuts off. Three times that and then you'll get a prompt asking if you want to boot in safe mode. Arrows control that menu and Enter selects it.

Comment: Windows 7 I believe also supports booting into safe mode by repeatedly pressing F8 while the computer is booting and you should get the option.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself, in the end.

Long story short, fixed it by installing the **ATI** drivers, not the Intel ones.

Steps:

Used DDU to wipe all existing display drivers in safe mode. (Thanks to headkase for the recommendation.)

Installed the *ATI* driver instead. Apparently the ATI driver package for switchable graphics cards has both the ATI and Intel HD Graphics drivers.

Ran into some errors like "inf file not found" during driver installation, bypassed that by manually extracting and pointing Device Manager to the inf file via "update driver".

Two blue screens and a DDU-aided reinstall later, it somehow worked.

Ugh.